# Help : Solving Recurrence Relation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, catalan-numbers

I am doing a counting problem and I ended up with the following equations.

$$ D_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (D_{n-i}+v_{n-i}+v_i\cdot 2^{n-i-1}),\quad D_1=0, D_2=0, D_3=2, D_4=9. $$
$$ v_n = v_{n-1} + C_{n-2} + D_{n-1} ,\quad  v_1 = 0, v_2 = 1, v_3 = 2. $$
$$ C_n = n^{\textrm {th}}\quad \textrm {Catalan Number}. \quad C_1 = 1, C_2 = 2, C_3 = 5, C_4 = 14.$$

I want a formula which will generate the sequence of $v_n$?. Please guide me.

The only thing I have done solving this is taking the difference of $D_n$-$D_n-1$, which is:

$D_n= 2(D_{n-1} + v_{n-1}) +  \sum_{i=1}^{n-2} v_i\cdot 2^{n-i-2}$

and replacing $D_{n-1} + v_{n-1}$ with $v_{n} - C_{n-2}$ but it didn't work.

Comment: You included the generating-functions tag; have you tried generating functions on this problem? More generally, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Just to make sure there are no typos in your equations, I get the sequence of values for $v$ as $0,1,2,6,20,68,232,792,2705,9247,\dots$.. Is that right?

Comment: @Somos Yes that's right, perfectly. Can you please help me??

Comment: If $C(x)$ is the g.f. of Catalan numbers, then the g.f. for $v_n$ is $C(x)(x-2x^2)^2/((2-x)^3-7(1-x))$.

Comment: @Somos thanku very much. Also does there exits any formula which will generate this sequence????? I tried finding coeff of X^n in g.f but i failed.

Comment: Some kind of formula. The $(x-2x^2)^2/((2-x)^3-7(1-x))$ is the g.f. of  a sequence with a recurrence like Fibonacci and so is $a_n=u_1r_1^n+u_2r_2^n+u_3r_3^n$ where $r_1,r_2,r_3$ are roots of the denominator. Now $v_n$ is the convolution of $C_n$ and $a_n$.